# Photoshop: Change dimension of whole file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, page-layout

I'm using Photoshop for design a web page. Firstly, I created a file with `1280x1024` pixels. After designing, the I need my file with larger height, then I press `Command + T` for open resize tool.

Nevertheless, after I resize, I see that just the border of height is longer, but elements at longer space cannot be seen. As those additional space cannot print. I don't know how to deal with this problem. Please tell me.

Thanks :)

Comment: you shouldn't use the resize tool ... you should use the canvas size.

Comment: @hsawires ah. thanks. I can do by your help :D

Comment: Can you tell me, what is the differences between two methods ? thanks :)

Comment: this is a completely different commands .. resizing document and all its content and will stretch or condensed your artwork. while resizing canvas is resizing the dimension of the document only and keep your content and all your artwork at their real dimension.

Comment: I hope you can post this as an answer, so anyone else can easily see solution :D thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

As hsawires mentionned, what you're looking for is the Crop tool.
It looks like this in the toolbar.
[image: Canvas tool]
 You can also input hard or relative values through the "Image -> Canvas Size" menu.

[image: Canvas size menu]

Checking the "Relative" box will set the values to zero and any value put inside the boxes will ADD to the current canvas size. You can also use a "-" before the number to substract from the canvas size.

The box with the arrows helps you choose in which direction you want the canvas to expand. By default, it is centered and will extend equally on all sides. I'll briefly explain, but it's much easier to understand by playing around with the tool in a blank canvas with a colored background and a few shapes laying around.

Clicking the "top center" arrow in the menu will create all new pixels at the bottom of your canvas.
When you look at the state of the arrows, it's easy to understand. This screenshot was taken after clicking on the top center arrow.

[image: Canvas tool manual resize]

The empty space under the bottom arrows is the new pixels that will be created.